# Is there a way to mass code refactoring in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing Roslyn code refactoring for my company's solution and I want to be able to apply it solution wide, The diagnostic with code fix allows me to apply the code fix in Document/Project/Solution.

But I want to write the code refactoring because I think that diagnostic should be used to detect error and improve the code and my refactoring just changes the code slightly.
Is there a way to perform mass code refactoring in Roslyn?

Comment: https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator

Comment: You can make it a diagnostic of severity Hidden with code fix.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj, I've already looked for such examples in Roslynator repo. Unfortunately, I didn't find mass refactoring. Could you provide reference to the source file where mass refactoring is implemented?

Comment: You have to iterate through each document manually, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483970/1156131

Answer (score 1):

Actually this feature currently is not implemented for code refactorings but is is planned:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32461